# Third div element hidden beneath footer

Tags: html, css

This third div element hidden beneath footer as seen here: https://www.screencast.com/t/FAb4WyXfR

How do I get this third div element to show in its entirety?

**CSS / HTML :**

```css
.places {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.places h1 {
  align-content: top-left;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.places article {
  width: 390px;
  border: #FF5A5F 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.places article h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price_by_night {
  color: #FF5A5F;
  border: 4px solid #FF5A5F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.information {
  height: 80px;
  border-top: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
}

.max_guest {
  background-image: url("images/icon_group.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_rooms {
  background-image: url("images/icon_bed.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_bathrooms {
  background-image: url("images/icon_bath.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.user {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

/*footer*/
footer {
    position:fixed;
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    line-height:60px;
    border-top: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="8-places.css" media="all">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>


  <section class="places">
    <h1>Places</h1>
    <article class="home">
      <div class="price_by_night">$80</div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> John Lennon</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="apartment">
      <div class="price_by_night">$65</div>
      <h2>Apartment</h2>
      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Tina Fey</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="dorm">
      <div class="price_by_night">$20</div>
      <h2>Dorm</h2>

      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Lorie</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add

```
   body {
     padding-bottom: 60px;
   }
```

As Your `footer` is fixed element, Your `body` doesn't reserve any space in it. It just goes on top of everything that's in there at the very bottom. `padding-bottom: 60px` just makes extra 60px at the bottom of Your `body` where nothing can be in (as it is padding) and then your `footer` just lies on top of it. 
Plus, Your pasted example has one closing div tag (`</div`) too much.

Comment: My favorite answer @Mikelis Baltruks as it is the simplest to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bottom margin to the last `<article>` that's as tall or taller than your footer with:

```
article:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```css
.places {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.places h1 {
  align-content: top-left;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.places article {
  width: 390px;
  border: #FF5A5F 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.places article h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price_by_night {
  color: #FF5A5F;
  border: 4px solid #FF5A5F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.information {
  height: 80px;
  border-top: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
}

.max_guest {
  background-image: url("images/icon_group.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_rooms {
  background-image: url("images/icon_bed.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_bathrooms {
  background-image: url("images/icon_bath.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 45% 45%;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.user {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}


/*footer*/

footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

article:last-of-type {
margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="8-places.css" media="all">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>


  <section class="places">
    <h1>Places</h1>
    <article class="home">
      <div class="price_by_night">$80</div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> John Lennon</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="apartment">
      <div class="price_by_night">$65</div>
      <h2>Apartment</h2>
      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Tina Fey</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="dorm">
      <div class="price_by_night">$20</div>
      <h2>Dorm</h2>

      <div class="information">
        <div class="max_guest">3 guests</div>
        <div class="number_rooms">2 rooms</div>
        <div class="number_bathrooms">1 bathroom</div>
        <div class="user"><b>Owner:</b> Lorie</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  </div>

  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @j08691. I prefer the body{padding...} solutions as it's clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 100px bottom margin to article.dorm

```
article.dorm {margin-bottom: 100px; }
```

I was viewing it responsively, actually you need:

```
.places {margin-bottom: 100px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for being the first to answer @mayersdesign.

Answer (score 0):

just add some padding to the bottom of the body

```
body{
 padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: Good answer @Alessandro Messori. I prefer the other contextual answers that help me understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to have this object over footer change only `z-index` to higher than default of the footer.

Comment: Thanks @user3799089. If I knew more about z-index, I would use it, but prefer the body explanations.

Answer (score 0):

By using `position: fixed` on the footer, you removed it from the document flow, which is why it doesnt "respect" the other elements inside said flow and is placed on top instead.
However since the footers height is fixed at 60px, you can just add a bottom margin to your .places section (since that one wraps around all articles) to compensate.

```
.places {margin-bottom: 60px}
```

Comment: your solution is a close second. I prefer the body solution as it's clear to me. Also, thank you for a great contextual answer to help me understand why. I want to learn more about document flow.